# Animate processing while method work

Tags: jsf

I have a simple button, which execute method on click:

```
<h:commandButton value="click" action="#{taskController.startTaskUpload}"/>
```

How can I animate the process until the method is executed?

For example, I want when the user clicks on this button, a preloader appears on the page as long as the method is running.

Comment: How would you do this in plain HTML? Do it the same way here

Comment: I thought in jsf there are some standard methods to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Partly but the concepts are the same. Start by using ajax and in the onstart and onend show 'something'. Or start adding PrimeFaces... (without the need to use their ui component, you can use their blocking features). And also take a look at OmniFaces